# Library Installation

Tags: installation, shared-library

To clear my doubt consider I am installing an application 'something' from the software centre. 'something' depends on a library 'libx' whose version is x.0.2. So it gets installed. Now I want to install the library 'libx-x.2.2'. I am gonna download the source files and I decided to build it from the source.

So my doubt is, what happens to the previous version 'x.0.2' when I build 'x.2.2' from source? Also I do not have the -dev version of the library installed already. So what should I do now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you build stuff from source, you should be careful not to override files installed by the package manager - doing so may result in

- programs which depends on the library may (or may not) refuse to work with the updated version, depending on the changes in the library
- when a new version of the library arrive to Ubuntu repository, update manager will override your custom files without warning

Comment: Thank You!:) So what should I do to avoid this? 

Actually I built d-bus from source. But it was already installed. That made me to face a lot of problems, I was not able to access the USB port. 

Now I want to build Glib2.34.3 from source. So now I fear that it may cause problems with the packages that depend on glib.

Comment: @user118095: why do you do that? Why do you need to compile those libraries?

Comment: I need to install the latest version of the library. I didn't find the .deb package for the latest version.